# Fluent Error Invalid object name 'hibernate_unique_key'

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

When I Can pull data from my table fine but when I attempt to '`VerifyTheMappings`' Fluent I get an error of "hibernate_unique_key"

If I turn on the SQL profiler I see the following query being run:

```
select next_hi from hibernate_unique_key with (updlock, rowlock)
```

Which will blow up. Is there something Special you need to do to set up HiLo Mapping with Fluent NHibernate?

EDIT: After some further reading it appears that the issue might be with they Original setup. In this [link](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Your-very-first-NHibernate-application-Part-1.aspx) they are using HiLo

But they are also using

```
    Session = SessionSource.CreateSession();
    SessionSource.BuildSchema(Session);
```

Regardless it still is not work has anyone else had this issue before ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Session Source, as to why I am not sure